# Weightlessness on Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, speed

Would the following work?

Imagine one would

1) create a straight 4000 km long tube (at ground level), following the curvature of the Earth, wide enough to hold a pod the size of an aircraft cabin;

2) remove the air in front of the pod and make sure it accelerates to a speed of 28000 kph.

Would one achieve weightlessness inside the pod for ten minutes? If not, what are the obstacles?

Comment: The sudden stop at the end of the tube might be disconcerting but otherwise it's exactly the same as an orbit. If you made the tube 40,000km and arrange for it to join up the trip might be more pleasant

Comment: I agree, but I lack the budget for the 40K model. :)
The sudden stop, of course, could easily be avoided.

Comment: but you have funding for the transcontinental prototype?

Comment: I wish.:) Just curious why I couldn't find any reference to any such theory/project on the net.

Comment: My son once asked me if you had to go to space to be weightless. I had my car keys in my hand and told him to watch them while I gently lofted them up, holding my hand about an inch below them, and catching them on the way down. See? I said. They were weightless. It's a cheaper demo than a ride in the [*Vomit Comet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_gravity_aircraft).

Comment: An isomorphic variant of the question (but without sci-fi toys, sorry :) , and one that I also found surprisingly difficult to bump across online): a big fat rocket simply fired horizontally, propelling against air drag to reach constant orbital speed, and bingo: weightlessness. Right? (Just in terms of physics, of course, not feasibility. Other desperate googlers for the same topic might land here now; oh, hi, good to see you here! ;) )

Comment: That'd require a phenomenal amount of propellant and heat shields that'd be pounded during the entire trip. My tube solution (elaborated in one of the comments to the answer) is far more energy efficient. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, equating the acceleration due to gravity with centripetal acceleration, I get the following required speed (which differs slightly from your rough figure):
$$
  v=\sqrt{gr} = 28,455\,\mathrm{kph}
$$
but yes, assuming you were to get the pod moving at that speed before it enters the evacuated tube, then once it enters it will be in orbit just above the surface of the earth for the entire duration of its flight in the tube, in this case that duration would be roughly 8 minutes and 45 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely fast answer. I had been looking all over the net whether this idea has been contemplated, but couldn't find anything. Hence my curiosity about the obstacles, besides cost. In any case, it might eventually end up cheaper than repeatedly sending experiments up into orbit. Unless the energy required to create the vacuum would be greater than the energy required to put it into orbit, of course.

Comment: My pleasure.  It's a cool idea :)

Comment: I suspect the problem is more fundamental than money. Rather, high quality vacuums are *hard*. Call it 5 meters in diameter...I make it almost $8 \times 10^7\text{ m}^3$ to evacuate, and more than $6 \times 10^8\text{ m}^2$ of wall available to out-gas. Having fun trying to pump that down. Even neglecting the possibility of leaks (which you will have if only around the pumps).

Comment: I assume it wouldn't have to be a perfect vacuum. Just little enough gas for friction not to become a problem. "Propulsion" could be obtained by magnetic levitation.

Comment: Well the drag power is proportional to $\rho v^3$ where $\rho$ is the air density, so a 10% increase in velocity requires you to reduce the density by 30%. It's not a fair game. :)

Comment: I wonder if a pointy nose cone of 100 m would reduce drag?

Comment: Solved the air problem by having one "train" which is 6500 km long, inside which is another train that is 6000 km long, inside which is another train that is 5500 km long, etc. until you have one which is 500 km long, inside which the cabin moves.
All trains accelerate (for about 3 minutes) to a speed each of about 2000 kph, a speed at which the air doesn't pose too many problems. The end speed of the cabin will be 28000 kph, which can last, over a distance of 7000 km, for about 10 mins (excluding acceleration and deceleration).

Comment: @Domus +1 For the increasingly outlandish yet amusing ideas.

Comment: This entire thing would be a whole lot cheaper if we all just lived on the Moon, I'm afraid. ;)